# AngularJs MVC with a view made in html5 canvas with iio

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm new into angularjs and iio.

I'd like to build a js restfull client that has an animated 2D interface forms.

For the 2D interface i've thought of using iio library : http://iioengine.com/

I've also seen that Angularjs allows MVC, eases testings and includes dependecy injection. I'm interested in that too!

My question is: is the View and Controll in AngularJs exclusively the html input-output or it can be substitute by a component done in iio?